# combobox background change colour

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, combobox, background

I am wondering how to change the background of the combobox. I know you can normally select the combobox and then right click edit a copy and edit template, but because the combobox is part of a data template I can't select the combobox to do this, and I am wondering how else to do this? I have also tried to copy and paste a normal combobox template in. However I then get errors with the aero and aero 2 themes yet I have used this before in other solutions to my project. Can anyone help me at all?

**XAML**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TreeRootTemplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#F7F7F7" CornerRadius="3">
            <StackPanel Margin="2" Width="170" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="5"/>
                <ComboBox Width="140" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableSources}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem = "{Binding Source, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="0">
                    <ComboBox.Resources>
                    </ComboBox.Resources>
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Padding="5" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontStyle}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Why dont you just use the Combobox.Background property?

Comment: I have tried this also and there is no change at all to my combobox

Comment: Y you're right, never tried to change the color but the Background property dont work. Found [this tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24240.changing-the-background-color-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8.aspx) maybe that helps

Comment: When I tried the first "box" area because I can't do the edit a copy it just changes the items int he combobox :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to override the `default` template and style. You can use the default template, just change the applicable Background color.

Here's a good [example](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2012/2/20/customizing-wpf-combo-box-style).

**Edit**:

Here is the complete XAML to customize a `Combobox`. You can mess around with the different colors to get what you want. Everything that is 'PaleVioletRed' will be a background color, while 'Cyan' will be the background color of the selected item.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleVioletRed"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="Border"
                                Padding="5"
                                Margin="2"
                                BorderThickness="2"
                                CornerRadius="0"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent" >
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="Border"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    CornerRadius="0"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                     BorderThickness="2" />
                            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    CornerRadius="0"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                    BorderThickness="10" />
                             <Path x:Name="Arrow"
                                   Grid.Column="1"    
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Data="M 0 0 L 8 12 L 16 0 Z"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="True" />
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="PaleVioletRed" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton"
                                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
                                          Focusable="false"
                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ClickMode="Press"/>
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Name="ContentSite"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                Margin="10,3,30,3"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                    Style="{x:Null}"
                                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                    Focusable="True"                               
                                    Visibility="Hidden"
                                    IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup
                                Name="Popup"
                                Placement="Bottom"
                                IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                                AllowsTransparency="True"
                                Focusable="False"
                                PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid
                                  Name="DropDown"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"               
                                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border
                                        x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                        Background="PaleVioletRed"
                                        BorderThickness="2"
                                        BorderBrush="Gray"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ComboBox Width="200" Height="75" Background="PaleVioletRed">
        <ComboBox.Items>
            <ComboBoxItem>test</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>test</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>test</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>test</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox.Items>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just looking through it just now, will let you know if it is helpful

Comment: Let me know if you need a XAML example! :)

Comment: A XAML example would be amazing please :)

Comment: i just made an update. see the complete styles, and adjust to your liking.

Comment: Thank you your example was perfect :)